# Can't get unique data based on unique form click sent to php with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to setup a page that displays observations, and if one of the observations is clicked then it will send the observation number of the observation clicked to php. Then when they are redirected to a details screen it will populate the details of the observation clicked. I have tried many different ways to get this done, so my code is kind of all over the place, but It seems that no matter how I do it either the Ajax doesn't send the data or it sends the same observation number every time. To me it seems like the AJAX data attribute can't deal with i. This is being built in Intel XDK, which is a html5 app builder. That is why this is tricky because I can't use browser developer tools to debug.

Javascript

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){    
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/observationMain.php",
     data: { action: "observationID" },
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(observationID){
         for(i = 0; i <= observationID.length; i++)

         {

            $("#observationMainListView").append("<form id='form"+i+"'' method='post'><a id='observation"+i+"' class='list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_"+(i+4)+"' data-uib='twitter%20bootstrap/list_item' data-ver='1'><h4 id='observationNum"+i+"' class='list-group-item-heading'>"+observationID[i][0]+"</h4><p class='list-group-item-text'>"+observationID[i][1]+"</p></a><input name='observationNum' value='"+observationID[i][0]+"'></form>");


             $("#observation"+i+"").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/observationDetail.php",
                    data: $("#form"+i+"").serialize(),
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(observationNum){
                             document.location.href = 'observationDetail.html';   
                    }
                    });

                });

        }
    }
    });

    });


</script>
```

php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['observationNum'])){
$_SESSION['observationNum'] = $_POST['observationNum'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a web server? HAve you watched the request / response in the browser's developers tools? Have you installed the jQuery library properly?

Comment: If you inspect the list cteated on page load does the input `observationNum` have the correct value ? Also give it an `type="number"` to form it well.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just edited the question, but I am doing this in intel XDK, a html5 app builder. The library is included correctly, because I have been using ajax and jQuery on other parts of the app, and it works fine.

Comment: @Searching Yes because I can see the input field and it has the correct numbers.

Comment: Try setting  the data manually in ajax send and check if the backend is accepting this value.  Did u add the input `type` and `id` ? You've got it for ur header but not for the input. Make sure the name & id fieds are unique.Let us know yr finding

Comment: @Searching Yes, the backend does accept values, and populates the next page I go too. It's when I try to send a unique number. I will try making the input a unique.

Comment: I put alert("click"+i+"") right after the click function but right before the ajax call, and when I click any observation it always alerts "click2", so I think that is where this issue is. I'm not sure how else I could do this though.

Comment: I hope this is how you tried ..`$("#observation" + i + "").click(function () { alert("click"+i+"") ... });`

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for keeping the event handlers in the for loop? You could just give a class to the observations and set their respective form IDs as data attributes on them. Then set one event handler at the end which acts on the form specified by their `data-id`, to avoid all the confusing ID looping.

Comment: @ppajer I have the event handler in a loop so that it would have a unique form to look to be clicked. I'm pretty new to javascript, so I'm not sure how to set one event handler to detect which form is being clicked. I think I get what you are saying though and will give it a try.

Comment: @ppajer It took me a bit, but I got it working. I forgot about this, and I had to research event delegation. If you want to put it up at answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be crazy but check this line.The form's id property has an extra `'` may be that's causing the issue.

```
$("#observationMainListView").append("<form id='form" + i + "'' method='post'
```

I cant run the script but just give it shot.